SharePoint online REST not working by item(number)
Thank you in advance for your input.  I am not a developer; I know enough to work with the different APIs/endpoints.  I am running into an issue that has me stumped.
I have two tenants, tenantA migrated to tenantB.  TenantB source code for custom webparts no longer works.  From what I can tell, it's simply doing a rest query likeso:
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Site%20Pages')/items(734)?$select=ID,Title,Description0,EncodedAbsUrl
When I run this query, for exapmle on the source tenantA it returns the expected item.  When I run this query on tenantB, I get a 404.  If I remove the item number, it returns all items.  There are over 1000 items in this list, but that shouldn't be hitting any sort of thresholds.
Any tips?  Please and thank you.
Reindexed the list, ran manual queries against the endpoints, validated security,

Are you sure that item/page with ID=734 is available in the site page library? Go to your Site Page library, show ID column in the list view and try running API call for available ID value. Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks Ganesh.  Indeed, the item was there but the ID had changed (migration).  DOH!  I wrote a PnP script to go through each webpart and map the old ID to the new one.

Great, glad it worked for you. I have added detailed answer below. Please accept it as an Answer as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

I think you are getting this error because you are using wrong item ID (734) in SharePoint REST API query. Seems like item/page with ID = 734 is not available in your SharePoint site page library.
Try this:

Go to your SharePoint Site Pages library.
Show ID column in the list/library view by following: Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library.
Try running SharePoint REST API call for any available ID value in the list/library view.

